# Which Mongo version I have to use for PHP Version 5.6.12?

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect with MongoDB using PHP, but it throwing Fatal error:

> Class 'MongoClient' not found in D:\xamp\htdocs\soap\testmongo.php.

My PHP version is 5.6.12 and installed MongoDB version is 1.1.1.
I again tried to configure MongoDB version 1.2.11-5.4 but its not supporting.
How can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB 2.6 is good for PHP 5.6.12

https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/php/